# How do I add horizontal gaps above and below my horizontal XFCE 4.16 panel?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, customization, xfce-panel

I've been customizing my Xfce 4.16 top (main) panel. I've done so via the settings first and then modifying ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css but there's someting I can' acuieve. Or it works... sort of. Instead of appling the changes in the destop panels, they seem to work only on the login/lock screen. And even so, sometimes in the LightDM screen, the panel goes off screen.

I'm trying to add an horizontal spacing above and below Xfce4 panel so there is a gap betwen the panel and the screen edge at the top, and between the panel and any window below.

That's what I've tried so far:

```
.xfce4-panel {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
    border-top-left-radius: 13px;
    border-top-right-radius: 13px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
.xfce4-panel {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
    border-top-left-radius: 13px;
    border-top-right-radius: 13px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

My first option was to unlock the panel and ove it down a bit, but when detached from the top edge, it jumps automatically a ton of pixels (I think it's like 20 or so), and that's not what I've intended All I want is a ~5 pixel gap above and below. Does that have something to do with window snapping?

Plus, I've tried to make the panel shorter from the panel preferences. If I set it to, say, 96%, it decreases the size a lot (I think it's ñike 10% less). But then again, it works fine at the lock screen. I'm quite happy about how it looks on the desktop with that size, however. But it's quite puzzling anyway.

I've tried other things I can't remember (I've tinkered with the CSS code and tried a few things) but nothing seems to work.[image: Desktop] [image: Maximized window] [image: Lock Screen]